# limiting the size of web.py POST data

Tags: python, web.py

I'm creating a RESTful API using web.py and receiving data via POST using **web.data()** as follows:

```
def POST(self):
  data = web.data()
```

Now, when the size of data is above some limit (say 10MB) I want to return an error.

I know how to do it with **web.input()** by catching **ValueError**, but I'm not sure how to do it with web.data(). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`data()`](https://github.com/webpy/webpy/blob/master/web/webapi.py#L338) just reads `CONTENT_LENGTH` bytes (or until `EOF`) from `ctx.env['wsgi.input']`. So if you want to abort after a certain amount ouf bytes, just read from there directly (and set `ctx.data`), then you can control how many bytes to read.

Or if the `CONTENT_LENGTH` header is set, you can directly check it and abort if necessary without reading at all...